# Laravel Check if Any Records Exist with Today's Date

Tags: laravel

I have an Appointment class and in a blade template I am trying to check if the user has any appointments with today's date. There is a separate "date" column where the format is Y-m-d.

I have tried using `Auth::user()->appointments->pluck('date') === Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')`, but that doesn't work because `pluck('date')` returns 'Y-m-d H:m:s'.

I'm also trying `Auth::user()->appointments->where('date', Carbon\Carbon::now()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone))->count()`, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use laravel eloquent `whereDate` to get the record created today.

Eg: `$query->whereDate('created_at', today())`

you can do something like

```
Appointments::whereDate('date', today((auth()->user()->timezone)))
->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
->count();
```

or

```
Auth::user()
  ->appointments
  ->whereDate('date', today(Auth::user()->timezone)))
  ->count();
```

Comment: Ok, it wants me to add () after appointments and it'll work. I had no idea about today(...) and was using Carbon instead. This is great, thank you!

Comment: @MattPierce glad it worked for you so the different between `appointments()` and `appointments ` is the first one you will return eloquent query builder where you can chain bunch of where clause and so forth. `appointments` will return collection

Answer (score 1):

there is a method called `whereDate` in laravel would be better in this case

```php
Auth::user()->appointments->whereDate('date', Carbon\Carbon::now()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone))->count();
```

for more info check [`Additional Where Clauses`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)